# How to install so runs alongside windows 8

Tags: system-installation

How do i install Ubuntu so that when I turn on my computer, the DOS screen shows up and I can choose between Windows 8 and Ubuntu? -Dell Latitude E6400

Answer (score 0):

When you install ubuntu, you will get an option called `"Install ubuntu xx.xx alongside Windows"`

This will automatically install ubuntu alongside windows, and you can choose between them in the Grub Bootloader.

Read more here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Good luck!